# Linux: Maven exec:java cannot find the main class

Tags: java, linux, maven

I created a maven project and compiled using mvn compile. It produced the following directory structure:

```
maven-sample
|_____pom.xml
|_____src
|      |_____main
|      |      |_____java
|      |      |      |_____com
|      |      |      |      |_____Main.java
|      |      |_____lib
|_____target
|      |_____maven-status
|      |      |_____maven-compiler-plugin
|      |      |      |_____compile
|      |      |      |      |_____default-compile
|      |      |      |      |      |_____createdFiles.lst
|      |      |      |      |      |_____inputFiles.lst
|      |_____classes
|      |      |_____Main.class
|      |_____generated-sources
|      |      |_____annotations
```

Now that it was compiled, I tried to execute the program using exec:java (the mainClass was specified to com.Main in the pom.xml). It produced the following error.

```
$ mvn exec:java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-sample 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) @ maven-sample ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:246)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.434s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 15 18:35:36 EDT 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/367M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) on project maven-sample: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.Main -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I think the problem is that the compiled Main.class is just sitting in the classes/ directory without package, but I'm not sure. How do I let the exec:java know where the Main class is?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-sample</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>maven-sample</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>

          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>

          <configuration>
            <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
            <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>

            <mainClass>com.Main</mainClass>

            <arguments>
            </arguments>

          </configuration>

        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your <mainClass> tag is incorrect. As your class is not in the package 'com'

Comment: How do I make the Main.class go to classes/com/? Main.java is in com folder, so I don't understand why it didn't end up in classes/com/..

Comment: The Main.java did not have package declaration. I put the package declaration, and when I compiled, the Main.class was placed in classes/com/ directory. But, I'm still getting the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Main...